# ¿Cómo puedo cargar un select dinamico con javacsript o jquery en base al valor de un documento php que recibo?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Estoy tratando de cargar un select, con la opción marcada que viene por defecto desde la base de datos, el problema se me genera cuando yo juego con la propiedad selectedIndex del select y por ejemplo si el id de mi registro es 36 pero si embargo el valor que necesito que muestre es la opción numero 9 (consulta ordenada alfabéticamente), ¿cómo puedo hacer que me muestre la opción que yo quiero en base al valor que viene desde la base de datos?

Comment: Debería poner el código que has intentado, para poder empezar por ahi. Te recomiendo que leas [ask]

Comment: Por favor agrega aldo de código así estimulas a los demás usuarios a que te ayuden más rapidamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes interactuar entre el documento que viene por php y el javascript ya que se ejecutan en diferente momento, uno en servidor para generar dinámicamente la página y otro en cliente una vez la página ya ha cargado.

Aunque podrías crearte un campo hidden o guardar una propiedad data en cualquier elemento del DOM con el valor recibido por php y luego cogerlo con JS o JQuery y modificar dinámicamente la lista, lo que quieres hacer, si he entendido bien tu pregunta es más fácil hacerlo desde el servidor directamente y traer la opción ya marcada.

Entiendo que si lo que necesitas es cargar el valor "seleccionado" del `select` para ello, lo más sencillo es lo siguiente:

- Créate una variable bandera auxiliar que se llame por ejemplo `$selected`
- Cuando recorras el array de opciones para construir las opciones del campo `select`si coincide con el valor que quieres del documento php que recibes ponla con valor `$selected="selected";`si no `$selected="";` de ta manera que te dejará seleccionada la opción que quieras.

Con un ejemplo:

```
<select name="campo-select">

<?php
   foreach($opciones as $opcion) {
      if ($opcion['propiedad']==$propiedad_pasada_doc_php){
          $selected="selected";
      }else{
          $selected="";
      }

      echo("<option value=".$opcion['value']." ".$selected.">".$opcion['nombre']."</option>");
   }
?>

</select>
```

Comment: Hola, he tomado en consideración lo que me has dicho sobre los input type hidden y me ha servido. En la respuesta de abajo publicare mi solución final. Gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente forma (para que a otra persona igual le sirva):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#ciudadM > option[value="+$('#valorCiudadM').val()+"]").attr("selected", "selected");});
```

Dentro de mi script he puesto el código de arriba, en donde $('#valorCiudadM').val() representa el valor del input type hidden, de esta forma me selecciona la opción del select en base a un valor, en mi caso, en base al ID de una ciudad.